# seleccionar fila pasando un id datatable(Jquery)

Tags: javascript, datatables

Estoy trabajando con datatable de jquery.
Me gustaría poder seleccionar una fila (Añadir la classe seleted) pero pasandole un id.

Me explico, Cuando yo hago click sobre una fila, esta se sombrea, yo quiero que haga eso pero sin hacer click, por ejemplo pasandole un id de la fila.

Este es el codigo

```
tblProyectosFueraPlazo.on('init', function () {      
            var rowToSelect = '#row_' + '0';
            tblProyectosFueraPlazo.row(rowToSelect).select();
        });
```

Comment: y el codigo o se supone que adivinemos lo que tienes?

Comment: Gracias por la aportación Bryro, Lo único que tengo es un campo númerico. Te pongo un ejemplo. 1. También puede valer el 2 o incluso el 3. Entonces en la fila de la tabla (datatable de jquery) que tenga alguno de esos números me gustaría aplicar la clase "Selected"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para seleccionar la fila numero *x*, haces uso del selector eq(x). 
Ejemplo para seleccionar la fila 2 y añadir la clase selected:

```
$('#tblProyectosFueraPlazo tr').eq(2).addClass('selected');
```

Un saludo